How to find chords that imply a certain melody
While playing around with chord voicings, I came across something I particularly liked - an AbM7:
e --x--
B --4--
G --5--
D --5--
A --x--
E --4--

While fiddling around some more, I came across a simple melody by moving the 5th of Ab major, Eb:
e -----------------------
B --4h6--6\7--7--6--4h6--
G -----------------------
D -----------------------
A -----------------------
E -----------------------


Combining the chord and melody, I created a groove at 85 bpm:
e --------x--x--x---x-------------------------
B --------4--x--4---4----4h6--6\7--7--6--4h6--
G --------5--x--5---5-------------------------
D --------5--x--5---5-------------------------
A --------x--x--x---x-------------------------
E --4--x--4--x--4---4-------------------------
    1     e     +   a      1    e     +    a

I have been trying to find chords that can be used instead of that little melody I created while still implying the melody but am having no luck. To start, I just tried using the same M7 voicing where the 5th of the chord corresponds to notes of the melody, like so:
e --x--x----x--x--x\x
B --4--7----7--8--4\6
G --5--8----8--7--5\7
D --5--8----8--7--5\7
A --x--x----x--x--x\x
E --4--7----7--6--4\6

Which sounds okay, but I feel like there is potential to shave off some bulk of the repetitive sounding voicing and add more color through different chords. How do I do this? Do I need to use chords where the root is each note of my melody instead of the 5th like in my original AbM7? Are there specific chords that go well with/compliment M7s (9ths, 11ths, etc)? Do any of the chords need to be minor? Something entirely different?
As an example, could chords that imply this melody be matched with my AbM7 and the reasoing behind them explained? Thanks so much in advance.

I suspect that picking chords that imply a certain melody is virtually impossible. There are reasons why chord progressions cannot be copyrighted, but melodies and lead sheets can. There are also such things as contrafacts, which involve different melodies for the same chord progression (so the same chord progression can "imply" two wildly different melodies depending on the listener). Occasionally, you can even hear a piece of music that plays its harmonies before the version with the melody (and, in at least one such case, I thought the harmonies were cooler).
